# Delete lines between two patterns when there are multiple matches in python

Tags: python

Say my input file looks like this:

```
lines
BeginModeData apple
lines
EndModuleData
BeginModeData banana
lines
EndModuleData
BeginModeData orange
lines
EndModuleData
...
```

I like to delete all lines belong to "banana", so it looks like this:

```
lines
BeginModeData apple
lines
EndModuleData
BeginModeData orange
lines
EndModuleData
...
```

By now, my python code almost work, but it also any other "EndModuleData", that is not what I want:

```
linelist = open("infile.txt").readlines()
newfile = open('outfile', 'w')
flag = 1

for line in linelist:
    if line.startswith("BeginModeData banana"):
        flag = 0
    if line.startswith("EndModuleData"):
        flag = 1
    if flag and not line.startswith("EndModuleData"):
       newfile.writelines(line)
```

How to improve my little code to get it work? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
flag = 1

for line in linelist:
    if line.startswith("BeginModeData banana"):
        flag = 0
    if flag:
        newfile.write(line)
    if line.startswith("EndModuleData"):
        flag = 1
```

As a side note, it is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way:

```
with open("infile") as infile, open("outfile", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        ...
```

Comment: I am newbie to python. It will be perfect if someone make some explanations on these codes, especial the flag thing.

Comment: @user6255179: Just try to apply the `if`s to every line in the input file. Basically, you write to the output file if `flag` is True and set/unset it based on the two patterns.

Comment: :If I want to keep the section and remove all other section, how to do it?

Comment: Invert the logic: start with `flag = 0`, set to `1` when the section starts and to `0` when it ends.

Comment: I try to follow your comments, but still have double lines problem, please look here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113018/how-to-copy-lines-from-several-files-base-on-conditions-in-python). Am I did something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can read the entire file in one string and use Python's regex module [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to replace the whole pattern:

```
s = open("infile.txt").read()  # read everything into a single multiline string
newfile = open('outfile', 'w')

new_s = re.sub('BeginModeData banana(\n.*?)*?\nEndModuleData\n', '', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
# match the replacement pattern non-greedily (*?) not to match all the way to the end

new_file.write(new_s)
new_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to python. I think its hard for me to understand regex module.