# How to copy lines from several files base on conditions in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am coding a little python scrpit to grab lines from several files according to a config file.

Config file looks like this:

```
[BeginObjects]
apple
banana
[EndObjects]
[BeginFiles]
path/fileA
path/fileB
[EndFiles]
```

Each of other files looks like this:

```
some lines
ObjectAlias apple
some lines
Begin
some lines
End
some lines
ObjectAlias pear
some lines
Begin
some lines
End
more object sections
```

I want to copy lines from above file to an new file like this:

```
ObjectAlias apple
some lines
Begin
some lines
End
```

Current code:

```
def getObjects (fileObj):#get object list from config file
    fileObj.seek(0)
    objList = []
    Tag = False
    for line in fileObj:
        if line.find("[BeginObjects]") != -1:
            Tag = True
        elif line.find("[EndObjects]") != -1:
            Tag = False
        elif Tag:
            objList.append(line.strip())
    return (objList)

def getFiles (fileObj):#get file list form config file
    fileObj.seek(0)
    fileList = []
    Tag = False
    for line in fileObj:
        if line.find("[BeginFiles]") != -1:
            Tag = True
        elif line.find("[EndFiles]") != -1:
            Tag = False
        elif Tag:
            fileList.append(line.strip())
    return (fileList)

def dummyRigs (fileObj, itemObj):#
    dummy = ""
    Tag = False

    for file in fileObj:
        with open(file, "r") as infile:
            for line in infile:
                for item in itemObj:
                    if line.find("ObjectAlias " + item + "\n") !=-1:
                        Tag = True
                        dummy += line
                    elif line.find("End") != -1:
                        Tag = False
                        dummy += line
                    elif Tag:
                        dummy += line
    return (dummy)
```

I use the first two functions to get file list and object list from a config file, then put them into the third function to copy lines from files, but it don't works as expected:
I get two list from the first two functions without problems, the third function not only give the lines I want, but double each line, and a lot of "End" line(my pattern in the third function). Looks like this:

```
ObjectAlias apple
ObjectAlias apple
line12345
line12345
more line6789
more line6789
End
End
End
```

Any helps is welcome.

Comment: When you use `for line in infile:` to loop through the lines in a file, `line` will NOT contain a trailing newline character.

Comment: Problems like these are where regular expressions can be your best friend!

Comment: Thanks, guys. I am newbie to python. I can't handle regular expressions at the moment. @John: I am newbie to python\coding, I can't follow you.

Comment: @user6255179 This line of code: `line.find("ObjectAlias " + item + "\n")` assumes that `line` ends with a `\n`, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check this is with `if ... in ...`, like so:

```
if "[BeginObjects]" in line:
    print "We found the string '[BringObjects]'"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Tag = False    
for line in infile:

    for item in itemObj:
        if line.find("ObjectAlias " + item + "\n") !=-1:
            Tag = True
    if Tag:
        dummy += line

    if line.find("End") != -1:
            Tag = False
```

You just need to change your if statement

Comment: Thanks for help. I want to copy lines from above file to an new file, currently, my code do not work.

Comment: @user6255179 - I would recommend giving more information than "my code do not work" because while SO users are willing to help, they're not willing to help if you either do not provide clarification or examples showing what you have tried.

Comment: @user6255179 I read your code and updated my post, It should help

Comment: @M Nour:If I reposition "Tag = False" line below "for item in itemObj" line, all I got is a lot of "End" lines

Comment: @M Nour: Much better! Still double lines like before, ie: 2-4 times of each line.